# How to remove ticks lines and labels when using add_gridspec in matplotlib seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

This is a follow on from my [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887293/how-to-adjust-height-of-individual-sublots-in-seaborn-heatmap)

I have the following code:

```
#Plot

cmap = plt.cm.GnBu_r
f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4,figsize=(20,10))
spec = f.add_gridspec(ncols = 1, nrows = 4, height_ratios = [1,1,1,.3])


ax0 = f.add_subplot(spec[0])
ax0 = sns.heatmap(df1,cbar=False,cmap=cmap)

ax1 = f.add_subplot(spec[1])
ax1 = sns.heatmap(df2,cbar=False,cmap=cmap)

ax2 = f.add_subplot(spec[2])
ax2 = sns.heatmap(df3,cbar=False,cmap=cmap)

ax3 = f.add_subplot(spec[3])
ax3 = sns.heatmap(df4,cbar=False,cmap=cmap)


axis = [ax0,ax1,ax2,ax3]
names = ['1', '2', '3','4']

for axi in axis:
    n = axis.index(axi)
    axi.set_title(str(names[n]))
    axi.set(xticklabels=[])
    axi.set_xlabel('')
    axi.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    h = axi.get_yticks()
    w = axi.get_xticks()
    axi.vlines(25, h[0] - 0.5, h[-1] + .5, linewidth=1, color="black")
    axi.vlines(50,h[0]-0.5,h[-1]+.5, linewidth=1, color="black")
    axi.vlines(75,h[0]-0.5,h[-1]+.5, linewidth=1, color="black")
    axi.vlines(100,h[0]-0.5,h[-1]+.5, linewidth=2, color="black")
    axi.set_ylabel('')
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

I have blacked out the names that I want to show but I am wondering how to hide the other x and y labels? eg all the decimals. I think they are related to the gridspec boxes for the 4 indivdual plots but i dont know how to remove them. I can remove the `xticklabels` and `xlabel` but it doesnt seem to work on the decimal points.

**Summary Question:**
How do I remove the decimal points in the plots? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You are adding the subplots twice.  Once w subplots and the second time w your add_subplot calls

Comment: thanks @JodyKlymak, that makes sense although i can't seem to be able to make it work without both? any recommendaytions to replicate the same graphy dimensions (with the height ratios) but keep the one subplot?

Comment: `f= plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))` and 
`spec = f.add_gridspec(ncols = 1, nrows = 4, height_ratios = [1,1,1,.3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you can remove specific ticks as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499156/removing-specific-ticks-from-matplotlib-plot). By using

```
yticks = axi.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[k].set_visible(False)
```

**EDITED**

Here is an example

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
y_dot = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
x_dot = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()

for x in x_dot:
    for y in y_dot:
        ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
        
l_x = [1,3,5]
for element in l_x:
    xticks[element].set_visible(False)

yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
l_y = [2,4,6]
for element in l_y:
    yticks[element].set_visible(False)
```

With the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Let's try. When i added this in it is removing the names of the plot and not the numbers. I am trying to do the opposite but not sure how to reference the grid that contains the decimals and not the name

Comment: Even if you use `.get_major_ticks()` and `[k]` to select specific ticks? I think right now you are applying it to the whole `xaxis` and that's why it removes only the names. I will try to provide an example asap.

Comment: Thanks! should i be replacing `k` with anything? it comes up with a `k is not defined` error

Comment: Check the example!